# Checking object's compile-time type in C#

Tags: c#, types, compile-time, compile-time-type-checking

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A m1 = new B();
        B m2 = new B();
        
        Console.Write("m1: ");
        m1.fun();
        Console.Write("m2: ");
        m2.fun();
    }
}

abstract class A
{
    public abstract void fun ();
}

class B : A
{
    public override void fun()
    {
        if (this.GetType() == typeof(A)) // ????
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        else Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

I want you to modify the `if` statement so that the program writes `A` for `m1` and `B` for `m2`.
I've been trying various combinations with `GetType()`, `typeof`, `is` and `as`, but couldn't make this work.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong if you actually need to do this in production code. Is this just a fun challenge?

Comment: @Sweeper no, actually, my proffessor gave me such assingment on last test and I couldn't solve this, but I still want to know how to do such thing next time.

Comment: There is no way to accomplish this with your above example.  You would have to modify the class definitions or the inheritance models to make something like this work, such as in Jerry's answer.  Also, this is actually not a compile time type check.  This is a runtime type check :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the rules of your assignment were, but if you have a virtual method in the base class and override it in the derived, you are always going to get "B".

If you are allowed to change the inheritance on the types you can do this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A m1 = new B();
        B m2 = new B();

        Console.Write("m1: ");
        m1.Fun();
        Console.Write("m2: ");
        m2.Fun();

        // m1: A
        // m2: B
    }
}

abstract class A
{
    public void Fun() => Console.WriteLine("A");
}

class B : A
{
    public new void Fun() => Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with virtual methods, but as generic method resolution uses the compile-time type information only, you can use this. You might e.g. define the following extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Fun<T>(this T instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

and call it as you do now call the virtual method:

```
m1.Fun();
```